# Stripe customer is created without the credit card information

Tags: django, django-forms, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup stripe as my payement gateway and having some issue.

I want my user to input their credit card info to be able to charge them later on. (aka creating a customer)

After entering all information and press enter, my customer is created on Stripe.com but the credt card information is not saved (so I cannot charge it later on).
On my database the token is saved and when i try to put a charge on the customer I got an answer from Stripe api "cannot charge, user do not have credit card" ...

Here is my code:

views.py

```
import stripe

def paiements(request):

    stripe.api_key = "sk_test_mytestapikey"
    utilisateur = request.user

    cc_save = Stripetoken.objects.filter(utilisateur= request.user).exists() #check if the user have already a stripe token.

    if request.method == 'POST': 

        token_cc = request.POST.get('stripeToken')  #request.POST['stripeToken'] give me an error.



        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                card = token_cc,
                description = utilisateur.email,
                email = utilisateur.email
            )

        Stripetoken.objects.create(utilisateur= request.user, token = customer.id , description= request.user.email) #save the customer information and token to charge later on

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/frontprop/tb/') # Redirect after POST

    args = {} 
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['cc_save'] = cc_save

   return render_to_response('b_param_paiement.html', args)
```

and my html page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

  <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_withmyid');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("#cbinfo").toggle();
  });
});
</script>




 <form action="/frontprop/tb/param/paiements/" method="POST" id="payment-form">  {% csrf_token %}
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Votre numero de carte bancaire:</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>CVC:</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <label>
        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY):</span> <br>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
      </label>
      <span> / </span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
   </div>
 <br>
    <button id="stripebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enregistrer la carte</button>
  </form>
```

FYI: I have followed this https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms

Thank you for your help

Comment: Judging by your comment about stripeToken giving you an error, it sounds like your JavaScript isn't quite working. Keep an eye on your browser's console for errors when you load the page/submit the form.

Comment: Thanks Tom, you were right by looking browser console (that i just discovered with your comment) there was an error with Jquery script, I put the Jquery script tag on top and it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Tom, there was a Javascript problem when loading/posting the form.
I have to move on top right after the stripe.js.

Thank Tom I am all set :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Plan that is free and assign them to that plan, you can later charge that customer with your one off charges as needed.

Comment: Thank for trying to solve my problem but it was indeed some javascript interference.